# How to build a string in ruby by calling block methods?

Tags: ruby, string-concatenation, block

What I want to do is define a method that gets the result of every method in a block (or calls every method in a block) and returns the resultant string...

For example:

```
def a_method(&block)
    ## build a string by calling each of the blocks methods
end

def brackets(str)
    '('+str+')'
end

a_method do
    brackets "foo"
    brackets "bar"
end

# desired output => (foo)(bar)
```

I tried putting `yield` in `a_method`, but as I expected that just returns the last evaluated expression from the block (in this case, `(bar)`).

I've looked around on how to build a string from calls inside a block, but can't find anything. I would have thought this would be quite a common technique.. could someone explain how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DSL object to handle this, giving you more flexibility:

```
class StringBuilder
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @strings << (@original_self.send method, *args, &block)
  end

  def build(&block)
    @strings = []
    @original_self = eval "self", block.binding
    instance_eval &block
    @strings.join(' ') #format as you like
  end
end
```

Now use where needed:

```
sb = StringBuilder.new
sb.build do
  brackets "foo"
  brackets "bar"
end
#=> (foo) (bar)
```

Comment: Just a caveat: because this relies on `method_missing`, in the unlikely event you try to build strings using methods already included in the `Object` class this won't work properly.  You can have the `StringBuilder` inherit from BlankSlate to get around this if need be.

Answer (score 0):

```
["foo", "bar"].map(&method(:brackets)).join
```

**UPDATE** Another way if you want to use various methods:

```
def a_method(&block)
    ## build a string by calling each of the blocks methods
    p block[].join
end

def brackets(str)
    '('+str+')'
end

a_method do
    [ brackets("foo"),
      brackets("bar") ]
end
```

Comment: thanks, but the question isn't really about the output, it's about specifically using block syntax.

Comment: I've seen code that does it without putting it in a list.. because yes my goal is to use multiple methods

Answer (score 0):

If you stricly want to use blocks to create your string, you will have to use clever ways to remember it. One of those ways is to use a string instance and eval the block on it.

```
def a_method(&block)
  "".instance_eval(&block)
end

def brackets(str)
  self << "(#{str})"
end

str = a_method do
  brackets "foo"
  brackets "bar"
end

puts str
#=> (foo)(bar)
```

Comment: hmm.. could I somehow respond to method calls from the block in the method that handles the block? (`a_method`) - what I'm trying to achieve is HTML-generation using blocks as demonstrated on http://tryruby.org/

Comment: looks like you're onto the right thing with `instance_eval`.... https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby/blob/f51c07138dab17cd9e7026fbe53528dc08c65f52/lib/popup.rb

Comment: I was typing up but you can just refer to PinnyM's answer